# error CS0103: The name `HttpClientFactory' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, mono, debian-based, xbuild

I'm trying to build this api_query https://github.com/CryptopiaNZ/CryptopiaApi-Csharp.git

```
$ uname -a
Linux kali 4.0.0-kali1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.0.4-1+kali2 (2015-06-03) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Building with mono:

```
$ xbuild --version
XBuild Engine Version 12.0
Mono, Version 3.2.8.0
Copyright (C) 2005-2013 Various Mono authors
```

And trying to build this project:

```
$ xbuild CryptopiaApi.csproj
XBuild Engine Version 12.0
Mono, Version 3.2.8.0
Copyright (C) 2005-2013 Various Mono authors

Build started 08.09.2015 16:13:55.
__________________________________________________
Project "/usr/src/cryptopia/CryptopiaApi-Csharp/CryptopiaApi/CryptopiaApi/CryptopiaApi/CryptopiaApi.csproj" (default target(s)):
        Target PrepareForBuild:
                Configuration: Debug Platform: AnyCPU
        Target GenerateSatelliteAssemblies:
        No input files were specified for target GenerateSatelliteAssemblies, skipping.
        Target GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
        Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because its outputs are up-to-date.
        Target CoreCompile:
                Tool /usr/bin/mcs execution started with arguments: /noconfig /debug:full /debug+ /optimize- /out:obj/Debug/CryptopiaApi.dll CryptopiaPrivateAPI.cs CryptopiaPublicAPI.cs DataObjects/Private/BalanceRequest.cs DataObjects/Private/BalanceResponse.cs DataObjects/Private/CancelTradeRequest.cs DataObjects/Private/CancelTradeResponse.cs DataObjects/Private/DepositAddressRequest.cs DataObjects/Private/DepositAddressResponse.cs DataObjects/Private/OpenOrdersRequest.cs DataObjects/Private/OpenOrdersResponse.cs DataObjects/Private/SubmitTipRequest.cs DataObjects/Private/SubmitTipResponse.cs DataObjects/Private/SubmitTradeRequest.cs DataObjects/Private/SubmitTradeResponse.cs DataObjects/Private/TradeHistoryRequest.cs DataObjects/Private/TradeHistoryResponse.cs DataObjects/Private/TransactionRequest.cs DataObjects/Private/TransactionResponse.cs DataObjects/Public/CurrenciesResponse.cs DataObjects/Public/MarketHistoryRequest.cs DataObjects/Public/MarketHistoryResponse.cs DataObjects/Public/MarketOrdersRequest.cs DataObjects/Public/MarketOrdersResponse.cs DataObjects/Public/MarketRequest.cs DataObjects/Public/MarketResponse.cs DataObjects/Public/MarketsRequest.cs DataObjects/Public/MarketsResponse.cs DataObjects/Public/TradePairsResponse.cs Implementation/AuthDelegatingHandler.cs Implementation/ICryptopiaApiPrivate.cs Implementation/ICryptopiaApiPublic.cs Implementation/IRequest.cs Implementation/IResponse.cs Implementation/PrivateApiCall.cs Implementation/PublicApiCall.cs Models/BalanceResult.cs Models/CurrencyResult.cs Models/MarketHistoryResult.cs Models/MarketOrderResult.cs Models/MarketOrdersResult.cs Models/MarketResult.cs Models/OpenOrderResult.cs Models/TradeHistoryResult.cs Models/TradePairResult.cs Models/TransactionResult.cs Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs /target:library /define:"DEBUG;TRACE" /reference:../packages/Newtonsoft.Json.7.0.1/lib/net45/Newtonsoft.Json.dll /reference:/usr/lib/mono/4.5/System.dll /reference:/usr/lib/mono/4.5/System.Net.dll /reference:/usr/lib/mono/4.5/System.Net.Http.dll /reference:/usr/lib/mono/4.5/System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll /reference:/usr/lib/mono/4.5/System.Web.dll /reference:/usr/lib/mono/4.5/System.Xml.Linq.dll /reference:/usr/lib/mono/4.5/System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll /reference:/usr/lib/mono/4.5/Microsoft.CSharp.dll /reference:/usr/lib/mono/4.5/System.Data.dll /reference:/usr/lib/mono/4.5/System.Xml.dll /reference:/usr/lib/mono/4.5/System.Core.dll /warn:4
CryptopiaPrivateAPI.cs(23,14): error CS0103: The name `HttpClientFactory' does not exist in the current context
CryptopiaPublicAPI.cs(22,14): error CS0103: The name `HttpClientFactory' does not exist in the current context
CryptopiaPublicAPI.cs(70,11): error CS0433: The imported type `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' is defined multiple times
                /usr/src/cryptopia/CryptopiaApi-Csharp/CryptopiaApi/CryptopiaApi/CryptopiaApi/../packages/Newtonsoft.Json.7.0.1/lib/net45/Newtonsoft.Json.dll (Location of the symbol related to previous error)
                /usr/lib/mono/4.5/System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll (Location of the symbol related to previous error)
        Task "Csc" execution -- FAILED
        Done building target "CoreCompile" in project "/usr/src/cryptopia/CryptopiaApi-Csharp/CryptopiaApi/CryptopiaApi/CryptopiaApi/CryptopiaApi.csproj".-- FAILED
Done building project "/usr/src/cryptopia/CryptopiaApi-Csharp/CryptopiaApi/CryptopiaApi/CryptopiaApi/CryptopiaApi.csproj".-- FAILED

Build FAILED.
Errors:

/usr/src/cryptopia/CryptopiaApi-Csharp/CryptopiaApi/CryptopiaApi/CryptopiaApi/CryptopiaApi.csproj (default targets) ->
/usr/lib/mono/4.5/Microsoft.CSharp.targets (CoreCompile target) ->

        CryptopiaPrivateAPI.cs(23,14): error CS0103: The name `HttpClientFactory' does not exist in the current context
        CryptopiaPublicAPI.cs(22,14): error CS0103: The name `HttpClientFactory' does not exist in the current context
        CryptopiaPublicAPI.cs(70,11): error CS0433: The imported type `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' is defined multiple times

         0 Warning(s)
         3 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.9231760
```

What does this err, means: "error CS0103: The name `HttpClientFactory' does not exist in the current context" ??

As I can google, `HttpClientFactory` is a part of namespace `System.Net.Http` which is included. Almost all of `libmono-` are installed on my system.

Edit:
Moreover, I've installed Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 14.0.23107.0 D14REL, latest version and errors are the same.

Edit2:
Probably, I've found the solution. It is Visual Studio 2013, not 2015. I do not know which mono shall it be, probably kind of downgrade would help to build HttpClientFactory...

Comment: In `CryptopiaPrivateAPI.cs` do you have a `using System.Net.Http;` declaration?

Comment: Yes, it is here: https://github.com/CryptopiaNZ/CryptopiaApi-Csharp/blob/master/CryptopiaApi/CryptopiaApi/CryptopiaApi/CryptopiaPrivateAPI.cs

Comment: what version of mono is this??

Comment: @knocte, see, I've mentioned version in the question. updated. Also, distributive is latest kali 2.0. Nothing more.

Comment: ok, great, can you test with recently released mono 4.2?

Comment: No, kali 2.0 is based on latest debian, there is no 4.2, only `ii  mono-xbuild                                             3.2.8+dfsg-10                    all                              MSBuild-compatible build system for Mono` which is 3.2.8.

Comment: @knocte, is there livecd with pre-installed mono 4.2? I can boot it with qemu.

Comment: not live-cd, but packages, just google it

Comment: I'm on the way with lxc-image. Wait for me, please.

Comment: @knocte, no, I'm using this http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/#debian-ubuntu-and-derivatives-alpha-channel, latest mono  `Mono, Version 4.2.0.0` and `XBuild Engine Version 12.0`, errors are the same. 3 errors without any change in my example.

Comment: @knocte, do you know, is it possible today - to download vmware image of windows 10 and install there visual studio? I'm searching across the microsoft.com site, and can not find this image.

Comment: that question is off-topic to this StackOverflow question, you should create a different question for that topic

Comment: @knocte, do you able to compile this project with mono?

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade the Nuget package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client to v5.2.2.
It's worked for me.